# READ_PHONE_STATE permission dialogue doesn't get shown

Tags: android, android-permissions, runtime-permissions

I need to request two permissions from a user: `READ_PHONE_STATE` and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. I do it as follows:

```
public void checkPermissions() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        ArrayList<String> missingPermisions = new ArrayList<>();
        if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            missingPermisions.add(android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);
        }
        if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            missingPermisions.add(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }
        if (missingPermisions.size() > 0) {
            String[] permissions = missingPermisions.toArray(new String[missingPermisions.size()]);
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST);
        }
    }
}
```

Method `checkPermissions()` is called in `onCreate()`.
From the two permissions I am requesting only `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` dialogue shows up. I have checked that during the execution `missingPermisions.size()` value is `2`. I have also tried to request only for `READ_PHONE_STATE` permission and in this case the dialog isn't showing up as well. My manifest contains those permissions as well:

```
<permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<permission android:name="android.permission.MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL" />
```

Why is my `READ_PHONE_STATE` permission dialogue doesn't show up? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my issue by changing this:

```
<permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<permission android:name="android.permission.MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL" />
```

Into this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL" />
```

There is actually a difference between [uses-permission](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html) and [permission](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html).

Answer (score 0):

Not all permission is needed to be asked by the user using dialog. Only dangerous permission are asked using dialog(like write storage).

Comment: I was considering this as well. `READ_PHONE_STATE` is one of dangerous permissions according to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_PHONE_STATE)

Answer (score 0):

Idk if you solved it already but... you don't need to check and then add them to the list.
Just make a `String[] {permision, permision}` and then check if they are granted. Even if one is and other isn't it will still prompt user to allow them.
This is how I did it:

```
// M = 23
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            final int SMS = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS);

            if (SMS != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                mDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                mDialogBuilder.setTitle(R.string.perms)
                        .setMessage(R.string.text)
                        .setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[] {
                                        Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS,
                                        Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,
                                }, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS + MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE);
                            }
                        }).create().show();
            }
        }
```

I cut out things that you wouldn't need so the code is not formatted properly but you can see, 2 permissions under 1 permission check and both are shown. Ofc, in this case, If user checks SMS and doesn't check RPS, dialog will not open again